# repo sync : ! [rejected] android-q-preview-4 -> android-q-preview-4 (would clobber existing tag)

Tags: android, git, terminal, android-source, repo

Today I did a `repo sync` to my AOSP repository and then I received some errors. these are what I received from terminal :

```
From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dtc
 ! [rejected]        android-q-preview-1 -> android-q-preview-1  (would clobber existing tag)
 ! [rejected]        android-q-preview-4 -> android-q-preview-4  (would clobber existing tag)
 ! [rejected]        android-q-preview-5 -> android-q-preview-5  (would clobber existing tag)
 ! [rejected]        android-q-preview-6 -> android-q-preview-6  (would clobber existing tag)
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/dtc
warn: --force-broken, continuing to sync
```

How can I solve that said issues?

Thank you .

Comment: git push --force

Comment: @JianAstrero I did git push --force and received this :     fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

Comment: Have you set upstream? i think you haven't

Answer (score 3):

It appears that "someone" has forced tags to move in a public project ... tsk, tsk.  In any event, I too encountered this problem and it took me longer than I care to admit to see the obvious solution: simply delete the offending tags from my local repo.  That looks something like this:

```
$ repo forall -c "git tag -d android-q-preview-1 android-q-preview-4 android-q-preview-5 android-q-preview-6"

$ repo sync
```

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with your code and the code of the repository.
It is possible that with this command you don't have more problems:

```
repo sync -c -d --no-tags --force-sync
```